# Create docker container that only contains webapp and server

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack, dockerfile

I have a project that basically has a structure like this: **(*)**

```
my_project/
    ├── server/
    │   ├── node_modules/
    │   └── server.js
    ├── src/
    ├── node_modules/
    ├── Dockerfile
    └── {multiple important config files for webpack and typescript etc}.json
```

I build the project with `npm run build`. This creates a `dist/` folder from the `src/` folder.

This is my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "prebuild": "npm run install:client && npm run install:server",
    "build": "webpack",
    "install:client": "npm install",
    "install:server": "cd server/ && npm install"
}
```

The final project only needs this: **(**)**

```
my_project/
    ├── server/
    │   ├── node_modules/
    │   └── server.js
    └── dist/
         ├── webapp/
         └── assets/
```

Now I want to create a docker image out of this.

I have a `Dockerfile` that's working now. It looks like this:

```
FROM node:boron
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 9090
CMD [ "node", "server/server.js" ]
```

But from my understanding, it copies everything I have in my directory and and then creates `dist/` folder and final docker image contains all of this: **(***)**

```
my_project/
    ├── server/
    │   ├── node_modules/
    │   └── server.js
    ├── src/
    ├── node_modules/
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── {multiple important config files for webpack and typescript etc}.json 
    └── dist/
         ├── webapp/
         └── assets/
```

How can I configure the Docker image to contain only the things in **(**)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `npm run build` will create the dist folder, which is what you want. After that you can remove the stuff that you don't need from the image by adding the following to the docker file

```
FROM node:boron
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .
COPY . .
RUN npm run build && /bin/bash -c "find . -not -name 'server' -not -name 'dist' -delete"
EXPOSE 9090
CMD [ "node", "server/server.js" ]
```

The command `/bin/bash -c "find . -not -name 'server' -not -name 'dist' -delete"` will just keep the server and dist folders

Comment: Sorry, it's not working I get `Step 5/7 : RUN npm run build && rm -rf !(server|dist)
 ---> Running in e6db783f4fa0
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build && rm -rf !(server|dist)' returned a non-zero code: 2`

Comment: Sweet! Actually it was solved using `RUN npm run build && rm -rf !"(server|dist)"`